# Which programming languages don't treat if as syntax?

Tags: syntax, programming-languages, language-design

In which programming languages is a conditional block (if) not syntactically different than a function invocation, including any "else" block of code to be executed in the false condition? In other words, in what languages could one define a function `an_alternative_if_function` which could then be invoked interchangeably with `if`?

For example, in Ruby, an if clause could be represented like this:

```rb
if(a > 20){
  puts("A is greater than 20.")
}
```

In that block, at least, `if` appears similar to any other function. It appears as if this `if` function is then passed an expression as an argument/parameter and also passed a block of code, as does, in fact, occur in the following functional Ruby code fragment:

```rb
def an_alternative_if_function(condition){
  yield if condition
}

an_alternative_if_function(a > 20){
  puts("A is greater than 20.")
}
```

However, Ruby is not a correct answer to my question, because there is no way for a Ruby function to accept an `else` clause in the way that `if` does. The following is **incorrect** syntax:

```rb
an_alternative_if_function(a > 20){
  puts("A is greater than 20.")
} else {
  puts("A is not greater than 20.")
}
```

***Update: My guess about Lisp below is incorrect. See Answers.***

<del>On the other hand, I reckon Lisp is one correct answer to my question, because in the following example code, `if` appears as a function which accepts 3 arguments:</del>

```lisp
(if (> a 20)
   (write-line "A is greater than 20.") 
   (write-line "A is not greater than 20."))
```

I'm unconcerned about the implementation details of compilers and interpreters. My only concern is whether `if` is syntactically distinguishable from other functions to the programmer reading the code.

Comment: I believe this is true of Lisp, but don't quote me ;--)

Comment: It seems to me that Tcl can do what you say.

Answer (score 0):

Smalltalk is one example where there is no special syntax for `if` - there's just an `ifTrue:` message of a boolean object.

If you consider pure lambda calculus a language, there's no special `if` there too - you just use Church booleans instead.

Same goes for combinatory systems like SK, with the same Church booleans.

In a Lisp, unless it's some very exotic lazy Lisp, `if` is a special form and not a function application, for function arguments must be evaluated first in most Lisps.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me that `if` requires lazy evaluation of parameters, whereas functions in most programming languages, including Lisp, use [strict evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy).